# How to delete aws snapshot for a terminated AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am unable to delete an AWS Snapshot and getting below error.

[image]

Unfortunately i have deleted the AMI before deleting the snapshot. Now, i am not getting Deregister option when i selected my AMI.

[image]

How can i delete my snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

I came to know that, the De-register option is not shown in the instances page as shown above.

We need to select AMIs option in left navigation bar displayed in the below attachment and then de-register your AMI and then delete your snapshot.

[image]